# pairs trading detrend the spread

Tags: pairs-trading, spread, hedge

I have calculated a hedge ratio that generates a mean reverting spread (stationary, without trends) 60-70% of the time. But the remaining 30% of the time, it seems like there is a trend in the spread. How do I handle such a case? Is there a way to account for that or make the spread stationary without trends?

Comment: When you say "make the spread stationary", do you mean construct a feasible spread trade; or do you mean post-process the spread data to eliminate the trend component?

Comment: Can you answer both the cases you have mentioned?